# **Recruited to** or **recruited into** a study?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Which one is correct?

> This pretest-posttest quasi-experimental study was made on 236 male dormitory students who had been **recruited to** the study through systematic random sampling.
>
> This pretest-posttest quasi-experimental study was made on 236 male dormitory students who had been **recruited into** the study through systematic random sampling."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb [recruit](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/recruit?q=recruited%20) normally means **to persuade someone to work for a company or become a new member of an organization, especially the army**.

The word **to** would normally be taken as an infinitive marker for the verb saying what people have been recruited to do.

> Young children have been forcibly **recruited to** perform combatant roles - [Bound to cooperate](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=iYmQ7jNHxoMC&pg=PA163&dq=%22recruited%20to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjelqL3s7nOAhWInRoKHTiTAx4Q6AEILTAD#v=onepage&q=%22recruited%20to%22&f=false)

The word **into** is a preposition that identifies the group that people are joining.

> .. significant numbers of children have been **recruited into** armed groups such as the RUF. [Research methods in conflict](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=iZeyAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA96&dq=%22recruited%20into%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj29u7ItLnOAhWEnRoKHd9TCsEQ6AEIOjAH#v=onepage&q=%22recruited%20into%22&f=false)

In the case of research studies, the subjects become members of the panel, and so **recruited into** is the appropriate term.

Here is a similar sentence about the conduct of research studies which uses the word **admit** rather than **recruit**: this should not affect the preposition.

> The purpose of the research and, in summary form, the eligibility criteria that will be used to **admit** subjects **into** the study (e.g., adults on medication for high blood pressure, diabetic patients on insulin; normal, healthy adults; etc.) - [Subject selection, recruitment and compensation](http://www.research.uci.edu/compliance/human-research-protections/irb-members/subject-select-recruit-comp.html)